# struct with pointer-to-parent-struct: best approach

Tags: c, pointers, struct, void-pointers

I have a large number of separate types of data (ie: processes, files, threads, functions, etc) that are defined in short, simple `.c`/`.h` files. Once I finished the implementation of the individual pieces and concluded unit/code-coverage testing, I moved on to connecting the pieces together.

The current implementation utilizes pointer-to-parent-`struct` via `(void *)` pointers in the code, ie:

```
struct typeB {
    int B;
    void *parent;
};

struct typeC {
    int C;
    void *parent;
};

struct typeA {
    int a;
    struct typeB *pB;
    struct typeC *pC;
};
```

**I used `void *` pointers due to how complicated some `struct`s are, and they won't compile if I use actual `pointer-to-struct-type` in place of `void *`.**

There are a few functions where `typeB` and `typeC` need to talk to each other, but they are rare. Also, both of these `struct`s never need to know about `int a` in the `parent`.

I could remove the `parent struct` pointers, and refactor my function prototypes/definitions to simple all accept `(struct typeA *)` as the argument, access the sub-structures, etc, but it seems overkill, as several functions just need to have access to `typeB`/`typeC` structures and their elements.

Is there a de-facto (non-cargo-cult-programming) standard for handling such an organization of structs (similar to the "don't cast `malloc()`" rule I see repeated so often on this site)?

Thank you.

Comment: Forward declarations. Use them.

Comment: @n.m. Fair enough. Beyond that, are there any significant concerns with using pointer-to-parent-struct logic? Thank you.

Comment: if you're trying to implement inheritance, make sure to align the parent pointer at 0th part of the struct so the offset would be 0

Comment: In C, there's no such thing as *parent*.  Pointers point; you decide, based on what they point to, to call that thing a "parent".  So your question becomes *concerns with using pointer-to-struct logic*, and I think you know the answer.  :-)

Comment: Consider smart pointers, std::{unique,shared,weak}_ptr.

Comment: @n.m. Note this question is tagged with "C"...

Comment: @tofro oops, forgot my readig glasses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used void * pointers due to how complicated some structs are, and
>   they won't compile if I use actual pointer-to-struct-type in place of
>   void *.

And what's wrong with forward declarations?

```
struct typeA; // forward declaration

struct typeB {
    int B;
    struct typeA *parent;
};

struct typeC {
    int C;
    struct typeA *parent;
};

struct typeA {
    int a;
    struct typeB *pB;
    struct typeC *pC;
};
```

As of your question: If you don't want/need to store paren as part of structure then you will need either

a) to pass parent address as a parameter, indeed, or

b) to define static variable like `struct typeA *current_parent;` and put there address of parent structure before calling any method operating with children.

Last solution is not thread safe though and is error prone.